# How to take certain parts in one array and convert them into another character in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mobile-application

I have created a code which recognises the colour `red` as "on" and the colour `blue` as "off", these *on's* and *off's* are then "pushed" into an empty array called `initial`, this can be seen below.

```
if (red > blue){
    initial.push("on");
    console.log(initital);
    console.log(initial.length);
    return true;
}

else {
    initial.push("off");
    console.log(initial);
    console.log(initial.length);
    return false;

}
```

when this is run and output like this is shown:

`[on, on, on, off, off, off, on, on, on, off, off, off, on]`

But I need to turn these *on's* and *off's* into dashes (`_`) and dots (`.`) and `.push` them in **another** array called `senseMake`, if that's possible.

The rules are:

- On for 1–2 time units = Dot
- On for ≥ 3 time units = Dash

Tried creating a for loop but isn't working, please help.

So the result of the array above should be:
`[_, ,_, ,.]`

The loop that I used was

`for (i=0; i<initial.length; i += 2)
        senseMake.push(".");
        console.log(senseMake);`

`for (i=0; i<initial.length; i += 3)
        senseMake.push("_");
        console.log(senseMake);`

Comment: Please add the loop you tried to your question.

Comment: Please add what your desired result for this particular array of "on"/"off" would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an efficient solution (no iteration) using regex. The whole thing could be around 2 lines, i.e:

```
var initial = ['on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off'];
var senseMake = initial.join('').replace(/(on){3,}/gi, '_').replace(/(on){1,2}/gi, '.').replace(/off/gi, '').split('');
```

But I've broken it into multiple lines in the snippet to make it easier to understand.

```js
var initial = ['on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off'];
var senseMake = initial.join(''); // join the elements of the array into a string
senseMake = senseMake.replace(/(on){3,}/gi, '_'); // replace every instance of 3+ 'ons' with a _
senseMake = senseMake.replace(/(on){1,2}/gi, '.'); // replace every instance of 1-2 'ons' with a .
senseMake = senseMake.replace(/off/gi, ''); // replace every instance of 'off' with an empty string
senseMake = senseMake.split(''); // split every character into the elements of an array
document.write(JSON.stringify(senseMake, null, '  ')); // display result in window
```

```css
* { font-family: monospace; }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the the on's and off's are being continually added to the array would it be the same just create a new variable such as 
`var array = initial`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you rephrase the question?...by the way, I've edited my answer to reflect your expected result. It now produces an array which looks like `[ "_", "_", "." ]`

Comment: As in the array is not static therefore an "on" and "off" is added depending on if the colour is red or blue. Therefore this:
`var initial = ['on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off'];`
can only be used if it is a set array meaning you know exactly what order they will be in.
Is there a way to say so that initial doesn't equal a set array?

Comment: My code will work no matter what sequence of ons and offs is present in the array. So as long as no other weird string like "quantum" is added to the array, you should be fine :)